How to trigger win11 snap layouts when hovering custom maximize button?
I have devloped electron based desktop app and for future extentions i disabled titleBarOverlay and made custom title bar buttons instead, now i wonder if there is any way to trigger Windows 11 snap layouts on custom maximize button?


So i had a similar problem and i started tweaking my BrowserWindowOptions with this custom title bar electron-custom-titlebar and with the option titleBarOverlay set to false, i get
 while set to true i get

